# NodeMCU broadcast to all clients

Tags: tcp, lua, broadcast, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to broadcast a request to all client that are connected to my esp8266 12f access-point

I used this to create a connection per client, means if there're 3 clients it will create 3 connections.

```
for mac,ip in pairs(wifi.ap.getclient()) do

   srv= net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
   srv:on("receive", function(client, b_response) srv:close() collectgarbage() end)
   srv:on("connection", function(client, b_request) client:send(request) end)
   srv:connect(80, ip)

end
```

I tried the broadcast ip `srv:connect(80, "255.255.255.255")` but nothing was sent

**The Problem :-**

What I used that every `srv` will overwrite the previous `srv` so I can not get a response if it was delayed, even so I can name every `srv` with a different name like `srv_1`, `srv_2`, `srv_3` but this take too much memory.

**What I want**

Create only one connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using TCP, which is inherently a single connection, point-to-point protocol. There's no such thing as a "broadcast" TCP connection. TCP simply does not work using broadcast. That's like trying to use a car as a boat.

If you're sending a small amount of information, you might try UDP instead. The drawbacks are that UDP is unreliable - you can't be certain your message was received - and you'd need a lot more code to receive a response, if you want one, and you'd need to build a reliability mechanism (retransmit if no answer received, detect retransmissions in case the answer was dropped) if you care about that.

I'd recommend that you check out the MQTT protocol - it's designed to make it easy to communicate with multiple clients. It's lightweight and MQTT clients run well on NodeMCU and Arduino processors. There's [an MQTT client built into NodeMCU's LUA implementation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/mqtt/).

The downside is you'd need an MQTT broker that all of your NodeMCU's will connect to. The broker is usually run on a more capable processor (a Raspberry Pi is a good choice) or externally on the Internet (Adafruit offers a broker at https://io.adafruit.com/), although [there are some implementations that run on an ESP8266](https://github.com/martin-ger/uMQTTBroker).